# XDG-OPEN is not recognized by WP CLI admin command

Tags: wp-admin, wp-cli

So i installed the wp admin package, but i can't seem to get her working, an error pops up telling me xdg-open doenst exist.. For install i used:

```
wp package install git@github.com:wp-cli/admin-command.git
Installing package wp-cli/admin-command (dev-master)
Updating ~.wp-cli\packages\composer.json to require the package...
Registering git@github.com:wp-cli/admin-command.git as a VCS repository...
Using Composer to install the package...
---
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.

Dependency resolution completed in 0.385 seconds
Analyzed 6619 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 474197 rules to resolve dependencies
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: wp-cli/admin-command:dev-master 384f6d3
 - Installing wp-cli/admin-command (dev-master 384f6d3)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
---
Success: Package installed.
```

Now checking if she's there

```
wp admin --info
'xdg-open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So what's going wrong, how can i get the wp admin command to run? btw, im running WP-CLI 2.0.1 on win10 from powershell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure windows is supported. Checking [this ticket](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/pull/2), it seems to yet focus on Linux (`xdg-open`) and Mac (`open`). You could create an issue on [their GitHub](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/issues)

Comment: So no wp admin support for win ? @kero :'(

Comment: Ticket filed @ https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/issues/15

Comment: Waiting for pull request to test usage of 'start' on win platform

Comment: Can you run `php -r 'var_dump(PHP_OS);'` from your powershell and if so, what does it return?

Comment: Or alternatively, can you [test this repository](https://github.com/kingkero/admin-command)?

Comment: @kero returns: string(5) "WINNT" gonna test the repo now

Comment: @kero unfortunatly it doesnt seem to work, installed package by running `wp package install git@github.com:wp-cli/admin-command.git` from powershell,
 
`Success: Package installed. 
'xdg-open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: You installed the old repo, try manually cloning it into `~/.wp-cli/packages/vendor/wp-cli/admin-command/`. Or wait for my PR

Comment: @kero, ran `wp package install git@github.com:kingkero/admin-command.git` same result `wp admin
'xdg-open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` ~Sarry :(

Comment: Can you test again? (see update in the GitHub issue)

Comment: Yes, @kero gonna test right now, i'll let u know

Comment: @kero, getting different errors now, see [this comment on github](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/issues/15#issuecomment-438958447) perhaps my updating with composer is just screwed, but manual install  also didnt yield succes unfortunatly..

Comment: the [ticket](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/issues/15) is resolved succesfully and closed. Waiting to merge with master.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened due to Windows not yet being supported.

With [PR#18](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/pull/18) this was resolved, update the package to the latest version and it will work on Windows machines.

Answer (score 1):

So `xdg-open` is not supported on Windows, therefor the code has been updated to check for a Windows OS and use `start`
Check out [this repo](https://github.com/wp-cli/admin-command/pull/18) if you cant wait for the merge with master.

Will leave this Question here untill everything is merged, so people experiencing a similar problem have some reference. Thanks @king-kero @schlessera for the quick support@github!

Comment: It is already merged into master, so happy `wp admin`ing ;)

Comment: @kero, so i ran, `wp package update` 
Using Composer to update packages...
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies through SAT
Looking at all rules.
Dependency resolution completed in 0.389 seconds
Analyzed 6740 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 486363 rules to resolve dependencies
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Generating autoload files
Success: Packages updated.
PS> wp admin --path='d:/d/sites/wp__1'
'xdg-open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Is there something im missing?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with this myself. Sounds like you have an old version of the package again. Try asking it on the GitHub